# Custom horizontal scroll calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-custom-view, android-calendar

I am developing an application in which I need to show the dates of months and year horizontally and scrolling. And on click of that, I need to show the data. The selected date should be highlighted and others are faded. I do not know how to show the calendar like below image.

[image]

This calendar I want to place the title bar and below that my data of that date is going to display.

Please guide me what should I do. Thank you and advance for your suggestions and guidance.

Comment: Use RecyclerView and align items horizontally. Also populate the dates from Calendar object.

Comment: It seems like simple `RecyclerView` implementation with Horizontal `LayoutManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

*HorizontalScrollView:*

add a HorizontalScrollView and a LinearLayout **container** (orientation=horizontal), then inflate programmatically every item (from .xml) and add them as childs under the **container**

*RecyclerView:*

create a recyclerview with his adapter, then create a layout manager with Horizontal property

```
LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

and set it to the recyclerview.